# Is it impossible to delete/move a file named "␀" on mac?

Tags: macos, finder, command-line

When I try to move, rename, or delete a file named `␀`in Finder, I get this error message:

> The operation can't be completed, because an unexpected error occured (error code -50).

With `mv`, `rm` or `find -delete` in Terminal

```
 rm: /Library/␀: Invalid argument
 mv: rename /Library/␀ to /tmp/␀: Invalid argument
 find: -delete: unlink(/Library/␀): Invalid argument
```

Can I move or delete this file in Mac OS X or do I have to use another operating system?

I even tried creating a file with this name in `/tmp` and it has not gone away since 8 reboots.

Comment: Have you tried using something other than a shell? E.g. Python's `os` module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be a 10.11 only problem, so it's impossible to delete on 10.11 at least, but you can very likely delete this on any OS X version other than 10.11, (I tried 10.4 and 10.10, and I could delete files with this character).

Comment: The bug is on the creation side. Otherwise many commands would fail on a Unix environment. For example `find -print0`, `xargs`...

Answer (score 8):

You can attempt to remove the file by its inode number. List the files in /Library
with the `-i` option

```
ls -il /Library
```

The first column is the inode number of the file. Then use `find`

```
find /Library -inum XXXXXXX -delete
```

where XXXXXX is the inode number of the file.

Comment: I don't know why my comment was deleted, but this just passes the filename to unlink, giving me the same "Invalid argument" error.

Answer (score 0):

Some newer macOS systems have trouble handling filenames that contain the "nul" character. The system interprets "nul" as the end of the filename, thus it cannot find the file. You could try to boot from another system, or use Target Disk mode and connect it to a Mac with an older macOS system (Mountain Lion etc.) Deleting it from recovery mode through the command line might work, or you could try fd0's inode number method.

Comment: There’s always going to be an inode to delete a file with a problematic file name. Probably far simpler than taking the filesystem to another os.

Answer (score -1):

```
mkdir tmp; mv * tmp; cd tmp; mv [A-Z]* [a-z]* [1-3]* ..; rm *; cd ..; rmdir tmp
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different and thank you for your answer. :) Unfortunately, short answers such as this don't really provide enough detail or context to help many users. If possible, it'd be good if you could add some more info on what a user needs to do with your answer? Also, you may want to read [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for tips on providing answers here.

Comment: As written it's even dangerous as the second `mv` command doesn't move all non-problematic files out of the `tmp` directory.