# How to remove or rename a folder with a "bad" name on El Capitan?

Tags: terminal, finder, macos

On my iMac I have a folder, left from preceding systems, named "ZipIt 2.2.2␀". I cannot delete or rename it, nor delete the files it contains, both from the Finder and from Terminal. Looking at [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/224505/is-it-impossible-to-delete-move-a-file-named-on-mac/310666#310666) and related answers I understand this is a bug of Mac OS 10.11 (and later?), connected to the presence of `NUL` character in the name.

I haven't an older Mac OS at hand. I tried to rename the folder with `Onyx` and `A Better Finder Rename 10` but without success. I also tried to boot from Mac OS Recovery but couldn't do anything useful.

Any ideas?

EDIT.

Here's the output I get from Terminal when using find:

```
    % ls -li
    total 0
    1067625 drwxrwxrwx+ 6 root  wheel  204 25 Mag  2011 ZipIt 2.2.2␀

    % sudo find . -inum 1067625 -mount -exec rm -rf {} \;
    rm: ./ZipIt 2.2.2␀/.DS_Store: Invalid argument

[... many similar lines ...]

    rm: ./ZipIt 2.2.2␀: Invalid argument
```

EDIT 2.

I thought of a possible way out, but don't know if it's viable. I could create a new user, transfer the offending folder to its desktop, then delete the user.

Do you think this could be effective? I'd like to try, but I'm afraid this could hang the whole system.

EDIT 3

As requested by Allan, here's the detailed content of the folder I cannot delete:

```
% find . -type d -name 'Zip*' -print0 | xargs -0 -J -t ls
./ZipIt 2.2.2␀:
Drop files here to zip (OS_X)   ZipIt.app
Read me.pdf

./ZipIt 2.2.2␀/ZipIt.app:
Contents    ZipIt

./ZipIt 2.2.2␀/ZipIt.app/Contents/Resources/ZipIt Help:
ZipIt Help idx  ZipIt help  faq     images
```

Comment: can you hardlink a directory to the inode, then you can at least delete the files.  Will repair file system in disk utility fix the directory name?

Answer (score 1):

Using the bash shell, you can try the completion feature. Example

```
Ravens-Claw:tmp garex$ mkdir "this\ is\ a\ bad\ folder\ with\ äü\ encoding"
Ravens-Claw:tmp garex$ ls -ltr | tail -1
drwxr-xr-x  2 garex  wheel   68 13 Jun 19:17 this\ is\ a\ bad\ folder\ with\ äü\ encoding
Ravens-Claw:tmp garex$ rm -rf "this\\ is\\ a\\ bad\\ folder\\ with\\ äü\\ encoding"/
```

Just type `rm -rf "this`, hit TAB key and bash will do the rest. Don't forget to close the ".

For files with strange filenames, you can try:

```
rm -- "<start typing filename and hit TAB key>"
```

Comment: Doesn't work: the usual sequence of "Invalid argument" appears. It is not a problem of the Terminal, it is the OS refusing to understand a name containing "NUL".

Answer (score 0):

Try removing it via the inode.

First, get the inode:

```
$ls -li

275505305 drwxr-xr-x   2 allan  staff    68B Jun 11 10:33 foobar
```

The inode is the first column of numbers.  Then using that number execute the following command:

```
$ find . -inum XXXXXXXXX -mount -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Where XXXXXXXXX is the actual inode of the file/directory you want to delete.

Comment: Tried that (with -r only) and only got a sequel of "Invalid argument". Also tried with mv instead of rm and got the same result.

Comment: Please post the output of the `$ls -li` and the exact command you used.  It's tough to see what's happening this far away.

Comment: I added that to my question.

Comment: It's owned by `root`  Preface the command with `sudo`.

Comment: I get `rm: ./ZipIt 2.2.2␀/.DS_Store: Invalid argument` and so on. I suspect there is nothing to do.

Comment: Not giving up just yet....`find . -type d -name 'Zip*' -print0 | xargs -0 -J % rm -rf %`

Comment: The result is same as before.

Comment: I've tried to create a directory with null chars but I still don't run into the issue you're running into.  Can you execute the command `find . -type d -name 'Test*' -print0 | xargs -0 -J -t ls` so we can see what's in the actual directory?

Comment: It's possible they corrected the bug in more recent OS. I added the output of the suggested command at the end of my question.